# Apache Ignite docker container with persistent volume on gcloud is not working well

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, ignite, persistent-storage

I am having difficulties with Apache ignite docker instance with persistent storage in gcloud.

The way I want to deploy an ignite docker instance in gcloud is when I push my code to github then it triggers a build and update new docker instance, it mounts and stores data in persistent volume automatically in Google cloud from what I created before. By the way I am not going to use kubernetes service for now because of some reasons with gcloud price.

I could deploy persistence-volume manually in console.

```
docker run -d -v persistence-volume:/persistence -e IGNITE_WORK_DIR=/persistence ignite-database:version
```

**[What is working]**
Push code to github to trigger to build new instance and update in gcloud.

**[What is not working]**
Automatically mount the persistent volume created before when I push the code to github.

I feel like gcloud command or cloud.yaml file are the ones I have to go through to fix it. It is not clear in what I have to do.

**[cloud.yaml] (github triggers to build new update)**

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v0.20.0'
  args:
  - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/database:latest
  - --cache=true
  - --cache-ttl=168h
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: [ compute, instances, update-container, database, --container-restart-policy=always, --zone=us-east1-a ]
timeout: 1200s
```

**[Dockerfile]**

```
# Start from a Java image.
FROM openjdk:8


# Ignite version
ENV IGNITE_VERSION 2.8.0
ENV JVM_OPTS -Xms512m -server -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true


# Ignite home
ENV IGNITE_HOME /opt/ignite/apache-ignite-${IGNITE_VERSION}-bin

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        unzip \
        wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /opt/ignite

RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/ignite/2.8.0/apache-ignite-2.8.0-bin.zip \
    && unzip apache-ignite-${IGNITE_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && rm apache-ignite-${IGNITE_VERSION}-bin.zip

COPY ./config/run.sh $IGNITE_HOME/
#COPY ./config/default-config.xml $IGNITE_HOME/apache-ignite@default-config.xml
#COPY ./config/persistence-config.xml $IGNITE_HOME/apache-ignite@persistence-config.xml
COPY ./config/control.sh $IGNITE_HOME/
COPY ./config/run_and_activate.sh $IGNITE_HOME/

#RUN sysctl start apache-ignite@default-config.xml
#RUN sysctl enable apache-ignite@persistence-config.xml

RUN chmod +x $IGNITE_HOME/run.sh
RUN chmod +x $IGNITE_HOME/control.sh
RUN chmod +x $IGNITE_HOME/run_and_activate.sh

CMD $IGNITE_HOME/run_and_activate.sh
EXPOSE 11211 47100 47500 49112
```

I am looking forward your advice.

Comment: Could you please share the errors you are getting when trying to automatically mount the persistent volume created before when I push the code to github?

Comment: Actually there is no error appear with upper yml and dockerfile. It works without persistent volume mounted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Kaniko and assume you're confident that your step works under Cloud Build (instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#running-kaniko-in-google-cloud-build)). You can confirm this by checking Container Registry for updated images.

I recommend not using `:latest` but perhaps your git commit (see e.g. [`${COMMIT_SHA}`](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)).

```
- name: "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v0.20.0"
  args:
  - --destination="gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/database:${COMMIT_SHA}"
  ...
```

Changing "container-restart-policy` changes how the VM will react when the container fails. What you actually want to do is force the restart (with your new image). I recommend you try:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args:
  - compute
  - instances
  - update-container
  - database
  - --container-image="gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/database:${COMMIT_SHA}"
  ...
```

This should force the VM to restart the container and, because the SHA will change with every change to your git repo, this should always pull the updated image.

When you create the instance (the first time), you will:

- mount persistent volumes (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#mounting_a_persistent_disk_as_a_data_volume))
- configure the env varz (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#setting_environment_variables)).

When you update the VM you do **not** need to reapply these mounts or recreate the env variables as they will be preserved. You can change them if you wish (but I think you don't need to).

So, something of the form:

```sh
PD="persistence"
gcloud compute instances create-with-container ${INSTANCE} \
--container-image docker.io/busybox:1.27 \
--disk name=${PD} \
--container-mount-disk=mode="rw",mount-path="/disks/${PD}",name="${PD}" \
--container-env=IGNITE_WORK_DIR="/disks/${PD}" \
...
```

> **NOTE** these are only needed during the VM create **not** update

Comment: Thank you. I am going to check when I get back home.

Comment: I have till same issue. do you have any idea yaml configures to  mount persistent volume on ignite docker container and store data permanently every single time after build up automatically? by the way, I agree your recommendation to use "COMMIT_SHA" is much better than latest tag. it makes much more clear.

Comment: I'll update my answer with some additional guidance

Comment: I tested it works out the way you explained. It seem like there is another problem  but I got a idea from your comment. After test it I will let you know. Thank you very much for your advice.